# React on Rails: Jsx and Coffeescritpt display @props

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jsx, react-rails

I am very new to React.

How do I display `@props` using `Jsx` and `CoffeeScript`?

In my file `records.js.jsx.coffee` I have the following code to display a record's date and title:

```
@Record = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<tr>
      <td>{@props.record.date}</td>
      <td>{@props.record.title}</td>
     </tr>`
```

The error I am receiving is `SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (5:11)`

I was hoping I could escape the code using the back ticks `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Record = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<tr>
      <td>{this.props.record.date}</td>
      <td>{this.props.record.title}</td>
     </tr>`
```

Using `this` instead of the `@` symbol worked.

From what I have read the `@` symbol compiles to `window` not `this` as I would have expected using CoffeeScript